# Servlet Exception when try to run servlet

Tags: java, servlets, classnotfoundexception, servletexception

I am a newbie in servlets. I am getting below sevlets exception.

My web.xml code.

```
    <display-name>LoginServlets</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Html form calling this servlet.

```
<body>
    <form action="login" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>UserName</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="SignIn" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Exception I am getting.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class LoginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Last day similar code working fine. But I also working git SVN I done setup an create new project with same code. But its not working.I also download some samples but none working.

This is my LoginServlet class. It is in JavaResources->src-mypackage

```
package com.loginservlets;
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.out.println("LoginServlet");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Get");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("HelloWorld");
        out.close();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Post");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code of your LoginServlet class. Is it in a package?

Comment: Please post the code of your LoginServlet.

Comment: I think you need the full packagename in servlet-class

Answer (score 5):

The name of your class is `com.loginservlets.LoginServlet`. Not `LoginServlet`.

Note that declaring the servlet in web.xml is redundant with declaring it with an annotation. There's no reason to declare it in web.xml since you can do the same with an annotation:

```
@WebServlet("/login")
```

Comment: Thanks Bro, Actually I created Servlet file from eclipse thats why eclipse automatically created this anotation. Before that I use web deployment descripter to launch servlets.

Comment: But @WebServlet("/login"); not working while @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/login"}) working fine.

Comment: actually `@WebServlet("/login")` should work fine according to docs, since you are mentioning only one attribute. But I had faced a similar problem and explicitly mentioning `urlPatterns` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have annotated your servlet class definition with `@WebServlet`, declaration of the same in `web.xml` is not necessary. Change `@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")` to `@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/login"})`